# How to declare a function during program execution?

Tags: java, reflection, function, java-me, hecl

This is something like [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_science%29#ECMAScript) where you can call a method simply by its name, and not a precompiled pointer to it.

Like in JavaScript you can:

```
var fun = function(){    alert("Hello World!");    }
fun();
```

Is something like that possible in Java/J2ME? How?

Comment: `java.lang.reflect` is something like reflection. Or possibly plain old polymorphism would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an interpreter for j2me, you could check out Hecl: http://www.hecl.org

You definitely can't do most of the 'fancy' things you can do in normal Java in J2ME.  The alternative is a series of if/elseif's that then call the function you want, but you still have to know that ahead of time so that you can write the code that does that.

Answer (score 2):

One way to imitate this functionality is to create a strategy class.

```
interface Function
{
    Object call(Object[] arguments);
}
```

To do what you suggested, simply do the following (a bit more verbose, as Java typically is):

```
static class Fun implements Function
{
    public Object call(Object[] arguments)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, world");
        return null;
    }
}

Function fun = new Fun();
fun.call(null);
```

Depending on the situation, you might be able to use better types or generics instead of `Object` and `Object[]` (in this case, I used them for maximum flexibility, but they don't give you much in the way of type checking so it's not ideal).

For more information, look at the [strategy design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

The common way of getting something like Javascript's closures is using anonymous inner classes. It's a lot more verbose, but it lets you do pretty much the same thing.

```
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
};
r.run(); // Prints "Hello, world!"
```

You can even reference variables in the enclosing method, if they're final:

```
public static Runnable makeGreeter(final String who) {
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
            System.out.println("Hello, " + who + "!"); 
        }
    };
}

// ... elsewhere in your program...
Runnable r = makeGreeter("world");
r.run(); // "Hello, world!"
```

This is standard stuff which has been in Java since the beginning. `Runnable` is a very handy interface which, according to the Javadocs, "should be implemented by any class whose instances are intended to be executed by a thread". `Runnable` can be used for a lot more than threads, of course, and is generally used (in the JVM and elsewhere) as "something that can be executed" - pretty much like a function in Javascript. Of course, if you want to pass arguments, you'd have to make your own interface, but those can be implemented anonymously as well. For example, using [@Imagist's `Function` interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411508/how-to-declare-a-function-during-program-execution/1411725#1411725):

```
interface Function {
    Object call(Object[] arguments);
}

// ...
Function helloSayer = new Function(){
    public Object call(Object[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello, " + args[0] + "!");
    }
};
helloSayer.call(new Object[]{ "world" }); // "Hello, world!"
```

**Edit:** This has nothing to do with reflection, of course, but there's no reflection in your example either - just an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Are you after the dynamic creation of methods or [Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)?

The first you can't do in Java but you could use an interpreter ([BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) if you want Java).

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a few ways:

You could create classes at runtime with [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel), but you have to create the bytecodes yourself. And the JVM's verifier might reject your class if your bytecodes look iffy. Not a super easy solution but doable.

Sun's Java 6 implementation includes [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino), the JavaScript interpreter, so you can perhaps do what you need if you're willing to use a little JavaScript.

I'm not too sure about this but I believe if you have the JDK installed, you can invoke `javac` from your Java program. `javac`'s output could be loaded at runtime with a custom `ClassLoader` class.